# How to get Lat,Long from google map?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have coded before to get `Lat,Long` from google map.But this time i am not sure what is wrong i see here the script from where i can get Lat ,Long.

```
   var mapData = {location: [{a:'%33%30%2E%32%33%36', b:'%2D%38%37%2E%39%30%38', cLat:'%33%30%2E%32%33%36', cLong:'%2D%38%37%2E%39%30%38', id:'75458vb', exact:false, zoom:15, maxZoom:20, type:'u'}], mType: 'property'};
```

But not sure how to get the actual `Lat,Long` i think it's encrypted any suggestion?

If it helps here is a sample [link](http://www.homeaway.com/vacation-rental/p3168186#map) from where i am trying to get the `Lat,Long` .

Comment: They're URL encoded, plug those bits into the following page and it will make more sense: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: @PeterJ oh so simple :)/

Comment: @PeterJ you can put that as an answer i will mark it, i just decode the url and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those values are URL encoded also sometimes known as [Percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). It is used to represent characters that would otherwise not be allowed in a URI and other similar situations. Many application frameworks provide decoding built-in, try searching for `UrlDecode`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("YOUR_URLENCODED_STRING");
```